# Regex: How to replace with the string literal "\1"?

Tags: regex, escaping, backreference

I have a string, say `r"a"`. I want to replace every `r"a"` with the string `r"\1"`, but my regex engine does not understand this.

I have tried:

- `r"\1"` -- crashes (can't match group 1 because there *is* no group 1)
- `r"\\1"` -- crashes (not sure why)

Is this a limitation of my (proprietary) regex engine, or is it a general problem? Is there an elegant way of solving it? (I could e.g. replace "a" by "/1" and then StrReplace( "/", r"\" )... but that's not *nice*!)

Comment: Without knowing anything about what the engine is, or why it is crashing on (apparently) well-formed input, I don't think it's very easy for anyone to help answer this.

Comment: This isn't a general problem with regular expressions. There is probably an escaping issue where you define your regex, could you post a code snippet?

Comment: The language is proprietary (and buggy). I just wanted to know what the standard way of doing this is.

Comment: the second form is generaly correct. But try with more \.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't your understanding of regex that's "buggy" (no offense meant)?

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the quotes as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way would be to use `r"\\1"` as a replace string. So if your proprietary regex engine/language chokes on a `\\`, you should fix this bug.

If you look at your example, you don't need a regex engine at all. But perhaps the example is simpler than the actual requirement...

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it is indeed rather more complicated than this. Nested StrReplaces, here I come!